# How to keep connection with Excel when data is changing rapidly?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am making a website for trading in which the feed is an Excel sheet. I wish to show the Excel data in gridview but the connection drops due to rapidly updating data (cells may change value 1-3 times in one second). I am using Ajax Timer with interval 1000.

Is there a way to retain the connection despite such rapid changes?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you make connection, and the error where you lose the connection?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a copy of the whole workbook into a temporary excel file, then read the contents of the worksheet you are interested in, and delete the temporary workbook when done. You can then repeat this process as often as your application can handle it. Once copied, you don't need to worry about the data changing.